# OS wide override of keyboard input?

Tags: c#, keyboard, .net-core

I'm trying to figure out how to write a .net core program that runs in the background of the users OS, the idea is if the user holds down on a hot key (such as caps lock or tab) the keyboard layout will change.

So if a user holds caps lock down the 'A' key will be remapped to 'L'

This would be system wide instead of just for any given app.

I found this solution: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/ but unfortunately it looks to be Windows centric and specific to the app in which it runs.

Answer (score 2):

Each platform have different architecture and underlying layers for handling IO and etc. 
It's platform specific task and should implement for each platform separately.